# How to get Gmail message id upon sending the mail?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm using the java mail API to send mails with a Gmail Account. My requirement is, when sending the mail, I need the message id (**or some unique id for email**) to store some additional info in my local database.

Since the Transport.send() method returns no value, I can't get an ID for the mail?

So two questions:

1) Can anybody help me with a way to get the Gmail id for the mail, upon sending?

2) Is the "Message-ID" the unique identifier for the mail?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaMail will set a Message-ID when it sends the message.  You can read it from the message after it's sent using msg.getMessageID().

Comment: This doesn't work. I construct a MimeMessage, but getMessageID() is only implemented in IMAPMessage -  a subclass with no public constructor. How do we do this?

Comment: Are you using [this method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getMessageID--)?

Answer (score 1):

Message-Id shall be unique identifier for mail ([see wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID)) but to get mail Id you have either generate it yourself (that's what mailers do - it is not generated by server), or if you use some kind of API that does that for you it either shall offer a method to retrieve this. If not, you may end in need to get that mail body (i.e. by BCC to self) and extract it from message.